# Need help solving a polynomial system

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning, groebner-bases

I need help solving the following system of equations:

```
A1*x*x+B1*y*y+C1*z*z+D1*x+E1*y+F1*z+G1*x*y+H1*x*z+K1*y*z+M1 = 0

A2*x*x+B2*y*y+C2*z*z+D2*x+E2*y+F2*z+G2*x*y+H2*x*z+K1*y*z+M2 = 0

x*x + y*y + z*z - a = 0
```

I tried to find a Gröbner basis using a mathematical package Mathematica Wolfram, but was unable to find (its memory is full and all). I do not have even the slightest idea how to solve it. Any ideas?

Comment: If you are having trouble asking your question in English, you can write your question in русском.

Comment: @J.M. OP has rewritten the question in Russian.

Comment: @J.M. [no](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange) - SE policy is having questions and answers in English only.  (Except for language-specific sites of course.)

Comment: Dmitry, you should also format your equations such that one can copy-paste it to his notebook. Have a look at the questions of other users and take a tour to see, how to achieve it. You can easily edit your question. By the way, please make it clear, if in the expression `xx + yy + zz - aa = 0` the variable `xx` (and the others) is a new variable, or it is x squared?

Comment: Sorry, x*x + y*y + z*z - a = 0  ~ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - a = 0 .

Comment: x y z - variable

Comment: The hope was that one of the Russian speaking users of this site (and I do know there are a number of them) would be kind enough to edit this post with an appropriate translation, @Shadow. But, you clearly know more than me about accommodating our dear user; feel free to help him, then.

Comment: @J.M. no, I do know of the general SE policy, and surprised you encourage users to act against it. Looks like OP was able to post in Engish after all, so guess all is good. (And yes, I did my best to try and improve the grammar)

Comment: @ShadowWizard J.M. is just fulfilling his campaign promise :) : http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6204161#6204161

Comment: thanks    vvvvv                       /vvvv

Comment: @Shadow, I consider this an exceptional case that can be easily greased through. Anyway, let's not have a meta discussion here.

Comment: It is necessary to solve system of the nonlinear equations in a general view privedyonnyy higher concerning variables x, y, z. The rest constants. What here isn't clear?

Comment: Is it possible to convert the original system of three equations of degree 8 (8 as the maximum number of roots {peresesenie two hyperboloids and scope}), all of which will depend on the x, y and z respectively?